# Method not found: 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.AuthenticationResult DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.VerifyAuthentication(System.String)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oauth, facebook-oauth

I am getting this error on oAuth login using Facebook.

```
var dd = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication();
```

My code is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         var  dd = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication();
         if (dd.IsSuccessful == true)
         {
             Response.Write("Login Sucess : " + dd.UserName + ", " + dd.ProviderUserId + ", " + dd.Provider);
             //Do something here like store this information in a database or in the session to remember the active login
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear. Have you added the proper assembly references and using statements? Are you perhaps referencing an older version?

Comment: added through nuget installer.